# Floating text to the right CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I float this text here:
[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="rightSide">
    <legend>Note:</legend>
    <p> If selecting recurrence please specifiy when the recurrence  ends with the Final Date (the last and final date of the event) field.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#rightSide {
    background-color:#eee;
    width:20em;
    padding:5px;
    padding-right:-20em;
    margin:0 auto;
    float:right;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    font:normal 12px Arial;
    color:#666666
}
```

Comment: Is `#rightside` within a div with the other content that's not wide enough to hold both of them width-wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this div after "Title" and make all other dive except "Note" div float left

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered but want to throw out something I use called http://960.gs for doing layouts. It will handle having to clear these floats, as well as nicely place everything where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

Make the left and right columns `display:inline-block;vertical-alignment:top;`